# Splitting a string inside brackets

Tags: php, regex

I need a string `VN7-572G-75AJ(NX.G6GSA.001)` to be split in an array like so:

```
[0] => VN7-572G-75AJ
[1] => NX.G6GSA.001
```

.. but I can't get the matching groups right:

```
$str = 'VN7-572G-75AJ(NX.G6GSA.001)';
preg_match('#\(/[^(]*/\) \((.*?)\)#', $str, $matches);
echo print_r($matches ,1); // outputs empty array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A totally non-regex solution is possible:

```
$str = 'VN7-572G-75AJ(NX.G6GSA.001)';
echo strstr($str, '(', true);       // Part 1
echo "\n";
echo trim(strstr($str, '('), '()'); // Part 2
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/dSYT6p). The first `VN7-572G-75AJ` part can be easily obtained with [`strstr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) (the *true* argument is the `$before_needle` value, we need all before the char indicated) and the second one gets all the substring from the first `(` till the end, and then [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) helps remove the `(` and `)` from the initial and trailing positions.

If you want your regex fixed, here is a solution:

```
$str = 'VN7-572G-75AJ(NX.G6GSA.001)';
preg_match('#^([^(]*)\(([^()]*)\)$#', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1] . "\n" . $matches[2];
```

Here is a [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/Zu58Fu)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `([^(]*)` - Group 1: zero or more symbols other than `(`
- `\(` - a literal `(`
- `([^()]*)` - Group 2: 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a literal `)` symbol
- `$` - end of string.

Another - simpler regex way - is to match any 1+ chars other than `(` and `)`:

```
preg_match_all('#[^()]+#', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[0][0] . "\n" . $matches[0][1];
```

See [this PHP demo](http://ideone.com/8OyR85)

Comment: Yes, there can be more approaches.

Answer (score 2):

This worked well here, of course, if you're looking for a regular expression

```
$str = 'VN7-572G-75AJ(NX.G6GSA.001)';
preg_match('/(.*?)\((.*?)\)/', $str, $matches);
echo print_r($matches ,1); // outputs empty array
```